# Jolt transformation on basis of another conditional value in the json

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to use jolt to transform a json payload and my input json looks like this

```json
{
  "root": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "ContactType",
            "value": "Company"
          },
          {
            "name": "HandlerName",
            "value": "XYZ"
          },
          {
            "name": "Reference",
            "value": "123-4443"
          },
          {
            "entities": [
              {
                "parent": {
                  "fieldName": "DefendantAddress"
                },
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "Address",
                    "value": "1662369113138 Somewhere Street"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "PostalCode",
                    "value": "XXXXX"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "name": "DefendantAddress"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am looking to transform the Address data based on value in ContactType field.

If ***`contact type`*** is **`Company`**, the output should be

```json
{
  "HandlerName": "XYZ",
  "reference": "123-4443",
  "companyDetails": {
    "address": "1662369113138 Somewhere Street",
    "postalCode": "XXXXX"
  }
}
```

If ***`contact type`*** is **`Person`**, then output should be

```json
{
  "HandlerName": "XYZ",
  "reference": "123-4443",
  "personDetails": {
    "address": "1662369113138 Somewhere Street",
    "postalCode": "XXXXX"
  }
}
```

I am able to check using my jolt spec if the contact type is Company or Person but struggling to navigate through the hierarchy to reach the child entities. This is my jolt spec. I am looking for implementation is ???? area or if another solution can be provided for the problem.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "root": {
        "entities": {
          "*": {
            "fields": {
              "*": {
                "name": {
                  "HandlerName": {
                    "@(2,value)": "handlerName"
                  },
                  "Reference": {
                    "@(2,value)": "reference"
                  },
                  "ContactType": {
                    "@(2,value)": {
                      "Company": {
                        ?????
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by diving deep into the innermost objects in order to match the **`value`** and **`name`** attributes at this level( **`"@(0,value)": "personDetails.@(0,name)"`** ), and then accumulate the subelements from the outer object after going some(*6*) levels up the tree to reach the level of it. Use *conditional* within the upcoming **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "root": {
        "entities": {
          "*": {
            "fields": {
              "*": {
                "entities": {
                  "*": {
                    "fields": {
                      "*": {
                        "@(6,fields)": { //traverse "{" characters 6 times to reach the level of outer "fields" tag
                          "*": {
                            "@(0,value)": "common.@(0,name)"
                          }
                        },
                        "@(0,value)": "p.@(0,name)"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "common": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "common": {
        "ContactType": {
          "Company|Person": { // "|" is "OR" operator
            "@(2,HandlerName)": "HandlerName",
            "@(2,Reference)": "reference",
            "@(3,p)": "personDetails"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you Barbaros Özhan but this transformation is always creating personDetails property no matter if ContactType is Company|Person. What I am looking for is  this output if contactType is Company                                                                                        {
  "HandlerName" : "XYZ",
  "reference" : "123-4443",
  "companyDetails" : {
    "Address" : "1662369113138 Somewhere Street",
    "PostalCode" : "XXXXX"
  }
}

Comment: I think you meant to fix this , It works now  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "common": {
        "ContactType": {
          "Company": { // "|" is "OR" operator
            "@(2,HandlerName)": "HandlerName",
            "@(2,Reference)": "reference",
            "@(3,p)": "companyDetails"
          },
          "Person": { // "|" is "OR" operator
            "@(2,HandlerName)": "HandlerName",
            "@(2,Reference)": "reference",
            "@(3,p)": "personDetails"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }